# Joins not matching where column value contains a space?

Tags: r

I have two data frames that both contain data for 33 London Boroughs. One is called temp2 and the other is called key_indicators. Both have a column called 'Borough' where the borough names are listed.

If I try to do an inner join or merge on those two tables based on the 'Borough' column, any borough that has a space in the name get's skipped (like 'Tower Hamlets' or 'Kingston Upon Thames').

I've tried comparing the values individually, by assigning the name of the first borough in both tables to variables 'a' and 'b' respectively;

```
    > b <- key_indicators$Borough[1]
    > str(a)
     chr "Barking and Dagenham"
    > str(b)
     chr "Barking and Dagenham"
    > a == b
    [1] FALSE
```

I can't fathom out why that comparison is failing?! I've tried checking various properties, but they both come back as the same, for example;

```
    > summary(a)
       Length     Class      Mode 
            1 character character 
    
    > summary(b)
       Length     Class      Mode 
            1 character character
```

Can anyone give me any pointers as to what I might be overlooking?

Comment: may be you have some special character for space in one of them.

Comment: Try `charToRaw(a) == charToRaw(b)` and see if you have a special character, or different space (normal non-breaking space is `20` from `charToRaw(...)`), or something unusual otherwise. If something is not `TRUE`, that's your issue.

Comment: Not familiar with charToRaw? If I type that I get the following output;

`
> charToRaw(a) == charToRaw(b)
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In charToRaw(a) == charToRaw(b) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
`

Comment: It implies that one of your space is not the correct one.  it may be encoded by multiple raw elementse

Comment: @SteveCollins - it means your first 7 characters are matches (`TRUE`), then the 'space' and everything from that point don't match. As @akrun and the error message suggest, the fact that `charToRaw(a)` and `charToRaw(b)` are not the same length probably means the 'space' is something unusual like a Unicode space, not your average old space. E.g.: `"Barking and Dagenham"` and `"Barking and Dagenham"` are **not** the same.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to remove the white space in the columns

```
temp2$Borough2 <- gsub("\\s+", "", temp2$Borough)
key_indicators$Borough2 <- gsub("\\s+", "", key_indicators$Borough)
```

and then join on these columns

Or as @thelatemail mentioned in the comments, replacing any space character with a single space would be better

```
temp2$Borough <- gsub("\\s+", " ", temp2$Borough)
```

Comment: Or if you wanted to fix the issue long-term, replace all space characters, including Unicode stuff, with a single space - `gsub("\\s", " ", "Barking and Dagenham")`

Answer (score 1):

Following akrun's suggestions. We could also use `str_trim` from `stringr` package to remove white spaces:

```
library(stringr)
temp2$Borough2 <- str_trim(temp2$Borough)
key_indicators$Borough2 <- str_tirm(key_indicators$Borough)
```